# Start a task without the use of Task.Run or TaskFactory.StartNew

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

Let's see:

> `Task.Run` Method (Action): Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool and returns a task handle for that work.

And

> `TaskFactory.StartNew` Method (Action): Creates and starts a task.

But my code doesn't have either of them. It can still be started and run. Why?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task t = AsynchronyWithTPL();
    t.Wait();
}

static Task AsynchronyWithTPL()
{
    Task<string> t = GetInfoAsync("Task 1");
    Task t2 = t.ContinueWith(task => Console.WriteLine(t.Result), TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);
    Task t3 = t.ContinueWith(task => Console.WriteLine(t.Exception.InnerException), TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);
    return Task.WhenAny(t2, t3);
}
```

It seems `Task.Wait` method starts the task, but is it a good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all. `Task.Wait` doesn't start a task, it waits for a task to complete.

You can start a new task by using `Task.Run`, `Task.Factory.StartNew`, `new Task(...).Start()` or by calling an `async` task (which I assume `GetInfoAsync` is).

An `async` method returns a "hot" task that was started before that method call returned. In your case you add continuations (`t2`, `t3`) to that task and then create a continuation on top of the two with `Task.WhenAny`.

If you're dealing with `async` tasks you don't need to start the tasks (and you didn't). If you want to offload work to the `ThreadPool` use `Task.Run`. Don't use `Task.Factory.StartNew` or `new Task(...).Start()` unless you must (which should be very rare).

---

I'm guessing (and I could be wrong) that what you meant to write is this:

```
static async Task AsynchronyWithTPL()
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(await GetInfoAsync("Task 1"));    
    }
    catch (AggregateException exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception.InnerException);
    }
}
```